# Make extension method / property available globally

Tags: extension-methods, kotlin

In Kotlin you can define extension methods and properties for existing classes:

```
operator inline fun Vector2.plus(other: Vector2) = Vector2(x + other.x, y + other.y)
```

This allows one to do this:

```
val result = Vector2(1.1f, 2.3f) + Vector2(2f, 4f)
```

Is there any way I can make this extension global so that I don't have to import this in every class that uses this?

Comment: Importing is almost never a problem when using an IDE, especially IDEA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that, because extension methods are resolved statically by the compiler.

Without an import, the compiler does not know about the extension.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't the Kotlin compiler figure out that when you import `Vector2` you also want to use `Vector2`'s extension methods.

Comment: The extension methods could come from anywhere on classpath, so there is no clear association and the compiler would have to scan all classes. Also, you could have conflicting extension methods. And lastly I think the designers wanted to make this explicit.